# Geochart "requested map does not exist" when deployed

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, google-visualization

By using the visualization API, i've been able to get a local map of Peru (by province) and got it working correctly while developing our application locally.

The code used to display the map is the following:

```
function cargarMapa(departamento)
{
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City'],
        [departamento]
    ]);

    var options = {
        region: 'PE',
        displayMode: 'regions',
        resolution: 'provinces',
        colorAxis: { colors: ['green'] },
        width: 465,
        height: 225
    };

    var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(
        document.getElementById('geochart_div'));
    geochart.draw(data, options);
}
```

And it works like a charm when working in my PC:

EXAMPLE:
[image: Geochart working in local environment]

It works whenever i run the application (im using Visual Studio 2012 and IIS 8) and also when i deploy it on my laptop (FYI, im doing so while being in my University network). BUT, when i deploy this in my University's local server (IIS 7.5), i get the following error:

[image]

FYI, i use other charts from the visualization API and they load perfectly

The code is exactly the same so, what could the issue be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the code works on your laptop, and you don't have any special server-side code running that could be causing the problem, I'm inclined to suggest that the problem is either network related or you are not loading the API properly.  Do you have a public-facing page on your university server I can test?  Can you post the whole HTML code so I can check to confirm that you are loading the API properly?

Comment: It has no public page but i'll provide the rest as soon as i get home. Thanks

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>

google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart,geochart,gauge,timeline'] });

</script>

Comment: You are loading the packages wrong.  Each package is an individual string in an array of strings; they should not be lumped together into a single comma-separated string: `['corechart', 'geochart', 'gauge', 'timeline']`

Comment: Wow, i hadn't thought about that.. I'm not currently at my University but i'll give it a shot there. Thanks for the help!

Comment: PS: i'll let you know if it works. If it does, could u post your answer by itself so that i can give you credit for it?

Comment: You didn't post how the `cargarMapa` function is being called, so you should also check to make sure that it is only being called after the API has finished loading (usually the draw functions are called in a callback handler from the google loader).

Comment: indeed:    google.setOnLoadCallback(cargarMapa(departamento));

Comment: Ahh!  That's the problem!  You want to pass the function as an argument to the callback handler, not call the function and pass its return value (`null`) to the callback handler.  I'll post an answer with the correct syntax for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is with this line:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(cargarMapa(departamento));
```

When you include `(<arguments>)` after a function name, you are calling the function, which executes immediately and returns some value (`null` in the case of `cargarMapa`).  `google.setOnLoadCallback(null);` doesn't do anything, and calling `cargarMapa` before the API is done loading causes issues, one of which is that your maps haven't loaded.

To fix this, create a new function that calls `cargarMapa(departamento);`:

```
function init () {
    cargarMapa(departamento);
}
```

and set this as the callback:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(init);
```

Notice there are no parenthesis (`()`) after `init` - this passes the function `init` to the callback handler as an argument, just like a variable (technically, in javascript, functions and variables are the same thing - they're all objects).